# Populating Django model fields doesn't work well

Tags: python, django

Here is what I am trying to do: reply to message. I'd like to use the same (django template) for creation as well as reply. I can pick out what the message id and I'd like to create a new message that uses the old message as shown below.

```
if '_reply' in request.POST:
            msgid = request.POST.get("msgid", "")
            readmail(msgid)
            message = ContactForm()
            oldmessage = Message.objects.get(pk=msgid)

            message.MySubject = oldmessage.MySubject
            message.MyMessage = oldmessage.MyMessage

return render(request, "viewmessage.html", {'message': message, 'loggedin': loggedin, 'toid': toid})
```

However, despite the values being populated in oldmessage.MySubject, these values do not appear in the view/template. The template is:

```
<form action="/viewmessage/" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <p>Subject:
                <p>{{ message.MySubject }}

        <p>Message:
        <p>{{ message.MyMessage }}


        <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="toid" value="{{message.MyToID}}" />
            <input type="submit" name="_delete" value="Delete" />
        <input type="submit" name="_spam" value="Report Spam" />
        <input type="submit" name="_reply" value="Reply" />
        <input type="submit" name="_send" value="Send" />

        </form>
```

Comment: This may or may not help you: [How invalid variables are handled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled). Sometimes when debugging this sort of thing I try to see if I can insert just the `message` object into the template. Also, for what it's worth, I don't see you adding `MyToID` to your `Message` class.

Comment: the values can be seen in oldmessage, but simply cannot get them into a new object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the idea of setting those attributes on the form object, but that's not how it works at all. You should be passing in your `oldmessage` as the `instance` parameter when instantiating the form object.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured out to do. I forgot about that. I used an initial string.